# Big O with removing an element each time

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Hi i am trying to find out the big-O of this algorithm.

I think it is n^2 but because the size of the sub loop is shrinking each time I am not sure.

```
 for(int i= 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = i; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            //Code here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a methodology using Sigma notation that is precise enough:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's O(n^2) if SIZE = O(n) and the complexity of (code here) is a constant…

You can do the math: for a fixed value of i, the inner loop is executed Size-i times, thus the total number of execution of the inner loop is sum_{i=0}^{size-1} (size-i) = size^2 - sum_{i=0}^{size-1} i  = size^2 - 1/2 size * (size-1) = O(size^2)